# PHP won't update

Tags: php, version, upgrade

When I run `php -v`, I get the following:

```
WARNING: PHP is not recommended
PHP is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software.
Future versions of macOS will not include PHP.
PHP 7.3.24-(to be removed in future macOS) (cli) (built: May  8 2021 09:40:37) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.24, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

When I run `brew upgrade php` I get `Warning: php 8.1.1 already installed`. How can I switch to from 7.3.24 to 8.1.1?

Answer (score 1):

I ran `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@8.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile` then `source ~/.bash_profile`, and I am now getting the latest version.